# Multiple source IDs error

Tags: migrations

I'm getting error

```
Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper</em>: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;map.sourceid2&#039; in &#039;field list&#039;: SELECT map.sourceid1 AS sourceid1, map.sourceid2 AS sourceid2, map.destid1 AS destid1
```

when trying to use two value ids in migrate yml file:

```
id: recipe_daily
label: Recipes
migration_group: recipe
status: true

source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
  data_parser_plugin: xml
  urls:
    - http://mysource.com/data
  item_selector: /recipes/recipe

  fields:
    -
      name: text
      label: 'Text'
      selector: text
    -
      name: title
      label: 'Title'
      selector: title
    -
      name: recipe_day
      label: 'Day'
      selector: '@day'
    -
      name: recipe_id
      label: 'Recipe id'
      selector: 'detail/@id'

  ids:
    title:
      type: string
    recipe_id:
      type: string

destination:
  plugin: entity:node

process:

  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: recipe_daily

  title: title
  text: text

dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - recipe
```

Since it's called ids I assume it takes multiple values but cannot find any examples anywhere. Any ideas much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried writing your ids as a list (with a leading `-`, like the fields section)?

Comment: Changed ids to the the same format as fields above - now not getting the error, but it doesn't process the items anymore:
Processed 0 items (0 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'recipe_daily'

Comment: When you make changes to source IDs, all existing meta data of this migration is broken. Remove existing data and the module, search for `migrate_map_YOURID` and `migrate_message_YOURID` tables in your DB and drop them. Then reinstall your module.

Comment: Wow, I'd have never thought of this, thank you very much, I spent most of the day pulling my hair out on this. I was using drush config-import to update my configuration from yml file but this apparently doesn't update db structure. My original syntax was correct in the end, with list syntax it reported the all 0 message I shared above.Anyway thank again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you used to have 1 ID before and that you added the second ID after you ran the migrations?

If your migrations aren't in prod, you can simply delete these tables and try again:

- `migrate_map_recipe_daily`
- `migrate_message_recipe_daily`

I think it should work.

If your migration is in prod, you might have to:

- Create a `sourceid2` column matching with your ID type
- Update the table keys to consider `sourceid1` and `sourceid2` as composite keys

I have tried the first one many times.

Comment: yes, thanks, but that's what @Hudri suggested, it works indeed. I haven't find this documented anywhere though.

Comment: Ok. I hadn't seen his answer because he had left a comment and not an answer. Good to see that it worked for you. And you're right. Certain corner cases are indeed not documented :(

Answer (score 0):

I will copy what [this comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/275578/multiple-source-ids-error#comment341716_275578) said into an answer, because it helped me. However, I was fortunate to see it at all, since it was only a comment, and with zero upvotes at the time. So I hope this gives the solution the visibility it deserves.

> When you make changes to source IDs, all existing meta data of this migration is broken. Remove existing data and the module, search for migrate_map_YOURID and migrate_message_YOURID tables in your DB and drop them. Then reinstall your module.

After dropping the table and reinstalling the module, I reran my migration without issues.