# Migration images_migrate_to_media did not meet the requirements. Destination plugin null did not meet the requirements

Tags: 8, migrations

I am trying to learn image import through Migration. I am going through this D.O. Article,
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-destination-plugins-examples/migrating-media

I am able to get the image_example migration to load. However, I keep getting an error with the images_to_media_example. It will not migrate and I get this error:

```
[error]  Migration images_migrate_to_media did not meet the requirements. Destination plugin &#039;null&#039; did not meet the requirements  

In MigrateToolsCommands.php line 866:
                                             
  images_migrate_to_media migration failed.
```

And when I try to rollback I get this:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'destid1' in 'order clause': SELECT map.sourceid1 AS sourceid1  
  FROM                                                                                                                   
  {migrate_map_images_migrate_to_media} map                                                                              
  ORDER BY destid1 ASC; Array                                                                                            
  (                                                                                                                      
  )                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                         
In Statement.php line 59:
                                                                                      
  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'destid1' in 'order clause'
```

I add the column 'destid1' into the migrate_map_images_migrate_to_media -- However I cannot get the import to work. Anyone solve this? Please help. I cannot find anything on D.O. to solve this and not sure where else to look.

There was this line in the images_example 'migration_dependencies: null' -- even if I remove that and reinstall the module the import still doesn't work. Please help!

EDIT: I am adding the code. I do not think this is the same thing as the question you mentioned.

```
id: images_migrate_node
migration_tags:
  - images
label: 'Import images (as files)'
source:
  plugin: embedded_data
  data_rows:
    -
      id: 1
      image: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg'
    -
      id: 2
      image: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/Patras_from_the_fortress.jpg'
  ids:
    id:
      type: integer
  constants:
    DRUPAL_FILE_DIRECTORY: 'public://images/'
process:
  pseudo_destination_filename:
    -
      plugin: callback
      callable: basename
      source: image
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: row
      message: 'Cannot import empty image filename.'
  pseudo_destination_path:
    -
      plugin: concat
      source:
        - constants/DRUPAL_FILE_DIRECTORY
        - '@pseudo_destination_filename'
  uri:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: process
      source: image
    -
      plugin: file_copy
      source:
        - image
        - '@pseudo_destination_path'
      file_exists: rename
      move: false
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:file'
migration_dependencies: null
```

AND the second migration:

```
id: images_migrate_to_media
migration_tags:
  - images
label: 'Migrate images to media'
source:
  plugin: embedded_data
  data_rows:
    -
      id: 3
      image: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg'
    -
      id: 4
      image: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/Patras_from_the_fortress.jpg'
  ids:
    id:
      type: integer
process:
  pseudo_destination_filename:
    -
      plugin: callback
      callable: basename
      source: image
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: row
      message: 'Cannot import empty filename.'
  pseudo_destination_path:
    -
      plugin: concat
      source:
        - '@pseudo_destination_filename'
  name: '@pseudo_destination_filename'
  field_media_image/target_id:
    plugin: migration_lookup
    migration: images_migrate_node
    source: id
  thumbnail/target_id:
    plugin: migration_lookup
    migration: images_migrate_node
    source: id
  uid:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: process
      message: 'No user for this file.'
    -
      plugin: migration_lookup
      migration: users
      source: author
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:media'
  default_bundle: image
migration_dependencies:
  required:
    - images_migrate_node
```

Comment: Did you change the source or destination IDs of your migration.yml? Then see [Multiple source IDs error](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/275578/multiple-source-ids-error)

Comment: Thanks Hudri, however, I don't think my issue is the same. At least in reading it I am trying something a little different. I added the 2 migrations to explain further.